# Weird number appearing on Header image in IE and edge browser works fine on other browsers

Tags: wordpress

WP site header has a weird number over header image when accessed in Internet explorer and Edge, the same page works fine in other browsers. tried resizing, and also using static image, same issue.

[Screenshot taken from IE and chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RT4Ru.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be a place where you can place a banner. 728x90 is a standard banner size.

Comment: I tried without header image and I still get the 728x90 when accessing the page using IE or Edge

Comment: It's probably a widget in your theme, or it is built into your template.

Comment: Hold on. If you are on free hosting, that banner may be a banner inserted by your free hosting provider.

Comment: it's a premium hosting, and the issue is limited to IE and Edge.